# NSIS: Writing to registry (not HKLM)

Tags: nsis

Please help me: I want to write some data to registry. You might say "Wait, wait, this is one of the basic features in NSIS!", but, I want to write to the *app* registry (HKCU, not HKLM). The main purpose is: when the installer installs my product it also installs my update manager. I just want to write the product installation directory to the Updater branch, so it can further fetch the update package and install it to the product directory.

Comment: Are you talking about HKCU or RegLoadAppKey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `RequestExecutionLevel admin` in your script and you are installing to `$ProgramFiles` then you are doing a machine/all users install and the installer should not write to HKCU. Your application must initialize its entries in HKCU and AppData the first time the user runs it. You cannot do it in the installer because UAC might run the installer as the "wrong" user.

If you have `RequestExecutionLevel user` in your script then you are doing a single user install and the installer should only write to HKCU and [Local]AppData.

Comment: I'm doing a machine installation. So I can't write to HKCU. But _how_ can I write (somewhere) the installation directory to use it (further) by the Updater?

Comment: Write it to HKLM. You are probably already writing the uninstall registration there.